# Launcher application missing white triangle arrow which indicates it is running

Tags: unity, launcher

This has happened since 11.10 if my memory is correct. If I minimize this application there seem to be no way that I know to get it back. Is this a unity bug or compiz bug? There is no triangle on both sides of the application, different from this question: [Sometimes applications stay in the background and have an empty white arrow in the launcher. How do I fix this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92749/sometimes-applications-stay-in-the-background-and-have-an-empty-white-arrow-in-t)

the screenshot [image: gimp not showing though still running]

gimp is running but I do not know how to bring it to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring it back to front using the 'expo' shortcut:

```
Super + w
```

That will bring all your running apps to the expo mode where you can see them all. Just click on Gimp and it will bring it to the front. You can also assign this expo mode to a 'hot corner' using the mouse pointer (up right corner for me).

Hope that helps